# QT/WebKit GUI pass selected HTML element data to Qt app

Tags: qt, qt4, qtwebkit

I'm going to collecect form inputs on web pages to fill them next time automatically based on input field name.

How to pass selected/howered HTML element data in QtWebkit to qt application? 
Like Firebug does.

Qt version: 4.6 / 4.7

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of qt4? 4.5, 4.6, 4.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some JavaScript to assign a unique ID or class to the element below the mouse pointer and then use the standard selectors with the [QWebFrame](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebframe.html) to locate it.

A more simple solution might be the selector `":hover"` but that will give you a whole bunch of elements which you need to filter because the mouse always hovers over `HTML` and `BODY` and all the other elements which are stacked upon each other below your mouse. So if the mouse is over a `span` in a paragraph, you will get at least `HTML, BODY, P, SPAN`.

Comment: Aaron, can you please, provide some examples or points to docs how to assign unique ID to the element below the mouse pointer or how to use :hower selecter in QtWebkit? Thanks.

Comment: found it:  
QWebFrame *frame = ui.webView->page()->mainFrame();  
QWebElement firstName = frame->findFirstElement("....");  
Now checking for mouse over event, and integration JS with Qt app